# For Loop Throws Error but While Loop Doesnt

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, while-loop

I am having trouble understanding an error I received when I tried to use a `for` loop in Python. Here is the loop that caused the issue:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
numList = [int(i) for i in list]
product = 1
for i in numList:
   product = product * numList[i]
```

The error was: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I was able to fix the problem by using the following `while` loop:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
numList = [int(i) for i in list]
product = 1
i = 0
while i < len(numList):
  product = product * numList[i]
  i += 1
```

What is wrong with the `for` loop, that causes the error?

Comment: You are indexing the list with its content in the *for* loop case. `3` is not a valid index.

Comment: Maybe try printing the value of `i` in each case.

Comment: Should be `product = product * i` as `i` is the number in the list. Give it a better name.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based in Python you are looping i as 1,2,3 the list array only has indexes 0,1,2

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The items in `list` won't always be the same as the indices. For example: `list = ["15", "2", "129"]`. I did at one point print out  `i` but it must have been on a iteration where I had a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the list value as the index.  You've confused the index with the contents.

```
for i in numList:
    product = product*numList[i]
```

Should be

```
for i in numList:
    product = product * i
```

or

```
for i in range(len(numList)):
    product = product * numList[i]
```

---

In the future, trace these problems by printing out the values you think are problematic.  In this case, the error message told you that the index was out of range, so you should have tried something like

```
    print i, type(i)
```

as the first statement of the loop.

---

Also, note that you can simplify your computation line slightly:

```
    product *= i
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with the `for` loop. I didn't realize that the line `for i in numList` wouldn't start at 0 since `list` indices start at 0. In regards to the `product *=i` I can't do that because the values in the `list` may not match the indices and I want multiply the number values together.

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't use `i` as an index at all.  It pulls the values out of the list.  If your list was `[True, 17, "foo"]`, then `i` would be `True` on the first iteration (interpreted as `1`), and `17` on the second -- getting your out-of-range error again.  If you got to the third iteration, you'd get a type error for trying to use a string as a list index.

Comment: Please try the `product *= i` change.  Note that it does *not* use the indices; it uses the values, without ever considering the indices.